# what does "find" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In football context, what does "find" mean?

> 37mins: Everton 0 Chelsea 0
>
> End to end stuff as both teams give the ball away and counter on each
> other. Chelsea looking to **find** Havertz aerially with several
> crosses while Everton try and **find** Gordon down the sides.

Answer (score 1):

It means "To successfully pass to or shoot the ball into."

You can find a player, or you can find the net.

Comment: Find the net means to shoot the ball in the net, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it means score a goal